powershell scripts for aws lifecycle policy
I have a power shell script which reads the lifecycle policy using
lifecycleConfig = aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket $bucketName
It returns the lifecycle policy but when there is no lifecycle policy it is returning error
An error occurred (NoSuchLifecycleConfiguration) when calling the GetBucketLifecycleConfiguration operation: The lifecycle configuration does not exist
and it runs into the next block of code.
So if my lifecycleConfig is null I dont want any error printing i want it to run next step
where i will add the new lifecycle policy.
please help me to remove the error if the lifecycle is not present.

Please post the exact code you're asking about - lifecycleConfig = aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket $bucketName is not a valid assignment statement in PowerShell on its own

Since you are using PowerShell: have you tried using the AWS PowerShell Module to achieve this instead? Otherwise, you will have to work with wrapping around the CLI, and having to navigate those error codes, etc. Have you tried Get-S3LifecycleConfiguration cmdlet? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-S3LifecycleConfiguration.html

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
